# Disable SharePoint 2007 Installation

Tags: 2007

I have an old SharePoint installation that is no longer in use (SP has been upgraded and moved to another server). I'd like to turn off this SharePoint 2007 install for a while so that it's not writing log files to the SQL server. Can I simply turn off some of the services to do this rather than uninstall SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, depending on what kind of user experience you need.

If the users still need to be able to access content, you can simply mark all of the SharePoint related databases to Read-only in SQL. (assuming your installation is at least Service Pack 1)

If your users no longer need to see the data at all, you have a few options.

- Disable all SharePoint related services (especially the Timer) and
  IIS.
- If the SharePoint installation is on a virtual machine, simply turn
  that Virtual Machine off
- Disable or stop the Sql Server instance that SharePoint 2007 is using (if possible)
- Detach all SharePoint-related databases from SQL Server

The largest source of data being written to SQL usually comes from Search Indexing, so if all of these options seem too drastic, you can peel back the frequent activities.

1. Go into Central Administration and click on your Shared Service
   Provider
2. Click on Search Administration - Content Sources
3. Set the full and incremental crawl frequency For each content source
   to "None"
4. Go to Control Panel - Administrative tools - Services and disable
   the SharePoint Timer job.
5. If your primary Site Collection has Auditing enabled, you can turn
   that off as well by going to Site Collection Settings - Audit
   Settings and unchecking all options